# How to handle PHP API POST select statement with 'IN' condition?

Tags: php, mysql, select, postman

I have sample php code as below to select data from database with **'IN'** condition:-

**product_model.php**

```
public function product_attribute_filter($data) {
            $sql = "select p.name,p.image from product p where  p.condition in (?)"; 

            $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($data['condition']));
            $records = array();
            foreach( $result->result_array() as $r ) {

            }
            return $records;
        }
```

**product.php**

```
public function product_attribute_filter() {

        $this->load->helper('my_check');
        $data = checkPostKey(array('condition'));
        $result = $this->Product_category_model->product_attribute_filter($data);
        if (count($result) == 0) {
            echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        } else {
            echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }
    }
```

How can I post it as `select p.name,p.image from product p where  p.condition in ('New','Used')` ??

Also, how can I try to call in POSTMAN? Currently this does not work.
Please help. Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtfBV.png)

**Edited**

I changed the following code according to Scuzzy sample code and its work.

```
 $array = array("New","Used");

                $placeholder = '"' . implode('", "', array_values($array)) . '"';

                $sql = "select p.name,p.image from product p where  p.condition in (" . $placeholder . ")";
```

Comment: I don't know what the POSTMAN does. For the binding you need a placeholder per value.

Comment: You're going to need to manually create the parameter placeholders still and flatten out any arrays you might have.

Comment: @user3783243 how can I do tat for placeholder? never try it before.

Comment: @Scuzzy how can I create placeholder? do u have any reference or sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition value should probably either be an array or comma seperated value, eg

`condition=new,used` or `condition[]=new&condition[]=used`

From there you can explode on the comma or work with the array to bind your values

you can leverage `$array = explode(',',$_POST['condition'])` if you go the former.

from there you will need to build up your `IN (?,?,?)` for each value perhapps something like this:

```
$placeholder = implode( ',', array_fill( 0, count( $array ), '?' ) );
$sql = 'select p.name,p.image from product p where  p.condition in (' . $placeholder . ')';
```

https://3v4l.org/q3SO9

this is counting the number of items in `$array` and adding the right number of `?` placeholders, of course you should account for no values provided.

You will then need to form up the right data binding into your SQL request.

Comment: Hi @Scuzzy, thanks for your prompt action. I changed my code in edited post and it works! Thanks!